# java call constructor without parameters from constructor with parameters

Tags: java, constructor

I have the next question. I have the code:

```
public class Foo {
  private int x;

  public Foo() {
    this(1);
  }

  public Foo(int x) {
    this.x = x;
  }
}
```

Can I call from `Foo(int x)` `Foo()` somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - doing so (calling `this()`) would creating a cyclic dependency between the constructors which isnt allowed at compile time